# Angular 1 app inside Angular 2

Tags: angular

Using Angular 2 app as the parent app, is there a way to load multiple Angular 1.x apps inside the parent app?

Note: Upgrading the Angular 1.x apps is not a viable option (business).

Answer (score 1):

You can load the angular 1 apps in iframes.  If they need to communicate you can use window.postMessage to talk back and forth.  I am currently doing something similar and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options viz.,

1. You can have them separate end points and point to them when needs
   to be redirected.
2. You need to wrap angular 2 inside angular 1, as things progress your angular1 will be removed.

Reasons for point 2:

1. Angular1 does not know sophisticated features as it is angular2.
2. The route of angular2 expects a Component, which is not possible to create using a angular1.